# I cant find why my code puttsute error messages

Tags: php, html

I have my website with a login and sign up page. But I get an error in the Sign Up part.

I have check if I have type wrong somewhere but I can't find anything wrong.

```
else if ($_GET['signup'] == "success") {
    echo '<p class="signuperror">Singup succesfull!</p>';
}
```

the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: signup in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\signup.php on
>   line 33

and here is where I set up my signup.

```
else {
    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I assume that first code is `signup.php` and line 33? Did you check if `$_GET['signup']` is set somewhere? Any other place where `$_GET['signup']` is used?

Comment: It isent used anywere else and the first else statmaent is on line 33

Comment: And the URL in your browser is actually `signup.php?signup=success`?

Comment: but why dose it put ote the eror if it isent runing the else statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send a `Location:` header with a relative path. Try to change

```
header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
```

to the fully qualified domain of yours:

```
header("Location: http://your-domain.example.com/signup.php?signup=success");
```

Comment: Mmm, yes you can. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location: "_An obsolete version of the HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 2616) required a complete absolute URI for redirection. The IETF HTTP working group found that the most popular web browsers tolerate the passing of a relative URL and, consequently, the updated HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 7231) relaxed the original constraint, allowing the use of relative URLs in Location headers._"

Comment: i fixed it butt tanks for the help

Comment: @kerbholz, ah okay, good to know! @VilgotKH: make sure you have the complete path to signup.php (e.g. `header("Location: http://your-domain.example.com/your-app/signup.php);` the above is only an example.

Comment: @VilgotKH What did you do to fix it?